# Push tag doesn't trig appveyor

Tags: deployment, git-tag, appveyor

I try to trig appveyor to start a build with `git push origin 'tag'`. 
Unfortunately appveyor won't start.
If I do commit and do normal pushing it starts, but with tag it won't.

here is my .appveyor file:
https://github.com/b00f/dana/blob/master/.appveyor.yml

Did I miss something?

Comment: Please find GitHub webhook which was sent after this tag push and provide GitHub Delivery ID, Commit ID and time Webhook was sent (in UTC or with time zone)

Comment: "ref": "refs/tags/v1.3",
  "before": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "after": "4058149273896036bcaa9493c4f5f42485340739",
  "created": true,
  "deleted": false,
  "forced": false,
  "base_ref": null,
  "compare": "https://github.com/b00f/dana/compare/v1.3",
  "commits": [...]

Comment: Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 22 Feb 2018 08:05:00 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not a good idea to answer my question. But I think the answer might help others to not waste a lots of time solving this issue. I contacted with AppVeyor and I got this answer:

> By the time this webhook was sent, your YAML configuration had the following:
>
> ```
> branches:
>   only:
>     - master
>     - develop
> ```
>
> This is annotated tag and as you can see from the webhook yourself, there are no way to get a branch name from this webhook. So in this case AppVeyor uses tag name as a branch. But as long as you set it to build only ‘master’ and ‘develop’, this build was skipped.
>
> If you need this kind of tags to be built, you can add some regex to your branches list which will cover your possible tag names. Something like this:

```
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - develop
    - /^v\d+\.\d+$/
```

It worked for me, hopefully it works for you also.